# I can't use the code I use in version v11.6.4 I use version v12.3.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
 if (
  newState.voiceChannel != null &&
  newState.voiceChannel.name.startsWith('- create ')
 ) {
  newState.guild
   .createChannel(`+ ${newState.displayName}`, {
    type: 'voice',
    parent: newState.voiceChannel.parent,
   })
   .then((cloneChannel) => {
    newState.setVoiceChannel(cloneChannel);
    cloneChannel.setUserLimit(2);
   });
 }
 // ! leave
 if (oldState.voiceChannel != undefined) {
  if (oldState.voiceChannel.name.startsWith('+ ')) {
   if (oldState.voiceChannel.members.size == 0) {
    if (!oldState.voiceChannel.members.size) return;
    oldState.voiceChannel.delete();
   }
  }
 }
});
```

it enters the named room and the new room is formed, the bot meets them, and then deletes them.
I just switched to the new V12 version, I'd appreciate it if you could help!
I couldn't find some of them, unfortunately, they don't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the things you need to change:

1. Use `newState.channel` instead of `newState.voiceChannel` (and the same for `oldState`).
2. Managers such as [`GuildChannelManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager) have replaced methods such as `createChannel`:

   ```js
   newState.guild.channels.create(...)
   ```
3. Use `newState.setChannel`, not `newState.setVoiceChannel`.

For more information on the breaking changes in v12, see [‘Updating from v11 to v12’ on the Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html).

---

The updated code:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
 if (
  newState.channel != null &&
  newState.channel.name.startsWith('- create ')
 ) {
  newState.guild.channels
   .create(`+ ${newState.displayName}`, {
    type: 'voice',
    parent: newState.channel.parent,
   })
   .then((cloneChannel) => {
    newState.setChannel(cloneChannel);
    cloneChannel.setUserLimit(2);
   });
 }
 // ! leave
 if (oldState.channel != undefined) {
  if (oldState.channel.name.startsWith('+ ')) {
   if (oldState.channel.members.size == 0) {
    if (!oldState.channel.members.size) return;
    oldState.channel.delete();
   }
  }
 }
});
```